# Adding keys to info plist when creating a notification via UserNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

To implement sending notifications to the user, I use the UserNotifications class

```
Center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .sound, .badge])


    UNNotificationRequest(id: id.rawValue, content: notification, trigger: trigger)
      notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
       if let error = error {
    
      }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

I read that it was necessary to enable permission in Info.plist and given key
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocalnetworkusagedescription

Do I need to specify the Local Network Usage Description key in the Info.plist file now and write NSLocalNotificationUsageDescription in the InfoPlist file or do I need to specify other keys, if so, which ones?

I tried to add NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription to my project, but it does not affect the system notification associated with the permission to send notifications. And I think this implementation is a bug

Comment: Local network access permission is not required for local notifications.

Comment: There is no Info.plist key needed for local notifications. But you have to handle carefully the authorization.